# Approximation of products of necklaces

Tags: number-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, necklace-and-bracelets

Let's consider approximation of $\prod_{p=1}^n N(p,a)$, $n\to \infty$, where the number of fixed [necklaces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necklace.html) of length n composed of $a$ types of beads $N(n,a)$: $\frac {(a-1)^{n+1}} {(a-3) \cdot n!} \prod_{p=1}^n \frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$, $a > 3$.

Please see [Error term in formula for products of necklaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163496/error-term-in-formula-for-products-of-necklaces) at MO.

My question is how to derive the such approximation and what the error estimation is?

I am interested in that due to $\frac {1-a^p} {1-a}$ looks like a generation functions of Mahonian triangles ([A008302](http://oeis.org/A008302), OEIS) and I would like to understand why so?

Comment: I don't know, but you might choose a different letter besides $p$, since $p$ is often reserved for a prime and your $p$ is not.